# How to get the confirm() value with C# code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ado.net, dom-events

I have a button which needs get the `confirm()` value to do the database operation. For example: when clicking the button, a message popup to confirm "yes or no", if yes, it will do the deletion operation in database, if no, it will clear the textbox.  How can I get the returned value from Javascript `confirm()` function.  Please advise.

```
string jScript;

jScript = "<script> function processConfirm(answer) {if (answer) {return 'Facilitator Deleted';}else {return 'Cancelled';}} var confirmAnswer = confirm('You sure to delete ?');var theAnswer = processConfirm(confirmAnswer);alert(theAnswer);</script>";    
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "keyClientBlock", jScript);         
/* SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TrainerFilter", conn);    
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;        
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim();        
cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;        
conn.Open();        
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();*/
```

Comment: How about cleaning up your code a bit so that it's easier to read? You can get help with the Markdown editor by clicking on the orange question mark above the edit box.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of confirm_proceed() in an asp:HiddenField
You can modify your script as follows:
 
     function confirm_proceed()
     {
       var hiddenField = document.getElementById('hiddenFieldId');

```
   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?")==true)
   {
     hiddenField.value = 'true';
     return true;
   }
   else
   {
     hiddenField.value = 'false';
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: How to access the value of hiddenField in the next Page_Load() call?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing, but assuming this confirm is tied to a button click, you would usually do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    processConfirm = function() {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
        if (!result) {
            alert("Cancelled"); //or set a label or whatever
            return false; //cancel postback
        }
        return true; //perform postback
    }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return processConfirm();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //perform the delete logic since because if you reach here
    //you know that the user confirmed

    //throw up an alert when the page is reloaded confirming that the deletion
    //you could also set a label here instead of an alert if you wanted
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "confirmDelete", "alert('User was deleted');", true);
}
```